# Create a new column in Spark dataframe that is a list of other column values

Tags: list, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a dataframe called 'df' structured as follows

| ID | name | lv1 | lv2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abb | name1 | 40.34 | 21.56 |
| bab | name2 | 21.30 | 67.45 |
| bba | name3 | 32.45 | 45.44 |

In Pandas, I can use the following code to create a new column that contains a list of the lv1 and lv2 values

```
cols = ['lv1', 'lv2']
df['new_col'] = df[cols].values.tolist()
```

Due to memory issues because of the size of the data, I am now using Databricks instead (which I have never used before) and need to replicate the above. I've created a Spark dataframe successfully by mounting the location of my data and then loading

```
file_location = 'dbfs:/mnt/<mountname>/filename.csv'
file_type = "csv"
   
infer_schema = "false"
first_row_is_header = "true"
delimiter = ","

df = spark.read.format(file_type)
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema)
  .option("header", first_row_is_header)
  .option("sep", delimiter)
  .load(file_location)

display(df)
```

This loads the data, however, I'm stuck on how to complete the necessary next step. I've found a function called `struct` in the Spark, however, I can't seem to find the corresponding function in PySpark. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably [`array`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array) function that you're looking for.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('abb', 'name1', 40.34, 21.56),
     ('bab', 'name2', 21.30, 67.45),
     ('bba', 'name3', 32.45, 45.44)],
    ['ID', 'name', 'lv1', 'lv2'])

df = df.withColumn('new_col', F.array('lv1', 'lv2'))

df.show()
# +---+-----+-----+-----+--------------+
# | ID| name|  lv1|  lv2|       new_col|
# +---+-----+-----+-----+--------------+
# |abb|name1|40.34|21.56|[40.34, 21.56]|
# |bab|name2| 21.3|67.45| [21.3, 67.45]|
# |bba|name3|32.45|45.44|[32.45, 45.44]|
# +---+-----+-----+-----+--------------+
```